# JavaScript: arithmetic operation fails

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I am doing following arithmetic operation in JavaScript:

```
var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
var result = (parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue) - 
              parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue)) +1;
```

When I provide the following input:

```
txt1 = 8946270000000000094
txt2 = 8946270000000000082
```

I am getting 1 as a result. Why?

Refer to [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tLKLy/1047/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum integer as parseInt can parse is `+/- 9007199254740991`. In your case the range is exceeded and hence it is giving the result as 1 since it is [overflowing the range](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5).

Also note that the [ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2) specifies that:

- There are 10 digits: (0-9)
- There are 26 characters: (a-z)

You need to use the [BigInteger library](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js) to deal with huge numbers like this.

Comment: @abcC:- You can use the BigInteger library: https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js